# ajax json weather auto refresh data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make an weather auto refresh  which is reloading for changes every 5 seconds. It loads perfectly first time on load but my setinterval is not working correctly. It goes of every 5 seconds but it doesnt update my menu even though changes has been made?

Here is what i got so far:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("demo");

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 } else { 
 x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
 var location = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude; 

 jQuery(document).ready(function(weather) {

 $.ajax({
 url : "https://api.wunderground.com/api/0ce1c4a981f7dd2a/geolookup/lang:AR/forecast/conditions/q/"+location+".json",
 dataType : "jsonp",

 success : function(parsed_json) {
 var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
 var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];

            var weather_html = ("<h3>Results of " + parsed_json.current_observation.display_location.city +
            "</h3>"  + "<p>Temperature: " + parsed_json.current_observation.temp_f + "</p>" +
            "<p>Current Weather: " + parsed_json.current_observation.weather + "</p>" + "<p>Wind Gusts: " +
            parsed_json.current_observation.wind_mph + "mph</p>" + '<img src="http://icons.wxug.com/logos/PNG/wundergroundLogo_black_horz.png" width="200"</img>');

            $('#returned_data').html(weather_html).hide().fadeIn("slow");


$(document).ready(function() {  
  weather(); //Get the initial weather.
  setInterval(weather, 600000); //Update the weather every 10 minutes.
});
 var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'];
 for (index in forecast) {
 var newForecastString = '' + forecast[index]['title'] + ' سيكون الطقس ' + forecast[index]['fcttext_metric'];
 var newForecastParagraph = $('<p/>').text(newForecastString);
 $(".astro").append(newForecastParagraph);
 }
 }
 });
 });
 }
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What `weather` suposed to be? The ajax request function, right? Now why the ajax function is outside it ?

Comment: In fact your code is a mess, it seems that you doesn't closes the `success` callback and `document.ready` is inside it. Pro tip: Learn to indent and it will solve 99% of your problems.

Comment: Function(weather) would make weather the parameter you are passing into the function

Comment: wait to edit full coding

Comment: @Gjohn sorry, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown by doing $(document).ready(function(weather) { }); the OP is thinking that the function name is weather. But function(weather) would in reality be a function with a parameter named weather and not a function named weather.

Comment: @Gjohn sure, that is what I tried to say in my first comment. Your answer is what I would suggest, actually.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown please see edit

Comment: @aligassan check Gjohn's answer, it is the reight answer.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown didn't  work

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var weather = function() {
      ... your ajax function here ....
    };

   weather();
   -- add your timer functionality here and wire it to call weather --
});
```

You have to declare weather as a function and then call the function. Then create your timer to repeatedly call the weather function in order to fulfill your update call.